# Navigation Drawer Changes background while scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I am working on a Navigation Drawer using `ActionBarCompact` to support all the devices. It worked as expected on **Android 4.4 & 4.2** devices. But when I Checked it in **Android 2.3** devices it shows the drawer. But when I **scroll** the drawer, the Background of the drawer **changes from black to white and it returns after scrolling**. I don't know, why it happens.

I Used the Code in this repository:

https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/androiddev/tree/master/ActionBarCompatEclipse/

[image]

**NOTE**
It works Perfect on Android 4.4 & 4.2 devices.

Comment: +1 because an image always worths a thousand words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert about `ActionCompact`, but for the `ListView` there's a solution for the background problem when scrolling:

Try to add

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

to the layout of the list view xml element. Does it work?

Comment: Looks Simple.But Worked Perfect.Thanks.                              Can you Say Wat it Does ???

Comment: Have a look at the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint